# Why Travis dont let me pass when i use Tabs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, github, tabs, travis-ci

I tried to add a pull [request on CodeMirror](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/pull/2860), and it seems that [Travis dont allow](https://travis-ci.org/codemirror/CodeMirror/builds/37703752) me to pass when i use Tabs on javascript.

Why is that so bad to use tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: That isn't Travis; it's part of their test script.

Comment: it hates tabs and prefers spaces?

Comment: https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#coding-standards

Comment: ah, so it is customized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Travis; CodeMirror's test script specifically disallows tabs (see [this line](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/test/lint/lint.js#L40)).

They [want](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#coding-standards) consistent formatting.

Comment: so it is up to the repo to fix their tests. thank you :)

Comment: @Abdelouahab, no, it's not "up to the repo to fix their tests". The project has an official style guide, linked in this answer, which includes "2 spaces per indentation level, no tabs". It's up to *you* to *conform to the project's style guidelines*. This is true of virtually any project you contribute to.

Comment: oh, now i get it, thank you :)